# FileNotFoundException on FileReader

Tags: java, android, filereader

My application needs to select a .txt document, open it, and read it line by line. I can get the file path no problem, but FileReader won't open the file, throwing a FileNotFoundException.

My Code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                filePath = uri.getPath();
                if (filePath != ""){
                    txtvFileSelected.setText(filePath);
                    try {
                        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filePath);
                        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                                new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                        int currentLine = 0;
                        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            //TODO: add string separation into floats here.
                            currentLine++;
                        }
                        // Always close files.
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        System.out.println("File not found '" + filePath + "'");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                    txtvFileSelected.setText("No file selected");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
05-14 09:14:51.409 24212-24279/com.examens.gilian.robotapplication OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-14 09:14:53.428 24212-24279/com.examens.gilian.robotapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb8ad5368 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb8988670
05-14 09:14:59.046 24212-24212/com.examens.gilian.robotapplication I/System.out: File not found '/document/primary:media/Data.txt'
```

Comment: `filePath = uri.getPath();`. That is not a file system path. Unusable.

Comment: And there is no 'and/or' about it, or 'can't figure it out' either. The exception is thrown by `FileReader`. The `BufferedReader` doesn't even exist at that point. And NB you are throwing it away when you do construct it, so when you solve this you will get an NPE trying to call `readLine()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> filePath = uri.getPath();

That is not a file system path so no wonder that nothing can be found.

Instead open an input stream and read from the stream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```